# SDWebImage thumb + original image loading issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, sdwebimage

I am trying to load thumbnail image first then request for original version of image , but not getting response for original image request .

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:thumbUrl completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

    if (image) {

        imageView.image = image;

        if (originalUrl != nil) {

            [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:originalUrl placeholderImage:image completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL){

                if (image) {

                    imageView.image = image;
                }

            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

Thanks ..

Comment: In case image is nil, I'd expect an error is passed into the completion block. Have you checked `error`?

Comment: i have checked it , not getting any response for second request . is there any issue with request inside completion handler ?

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't set image to imageView `imageView.image = image;` It will be done automatically.

Comment: @Che that's i agree , but how it related to my problem .

Comment: Actually, I checked both variants… Your and my… Everything works perfect… Are you sure in second call of `sd_setImageWithURL`?
I mean, originalURL isn't nil.

Comment: Could you check originalURL? Is it not nil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92971/discussion-between-che-and-riyaz).

Answer (score 0):

Try this case

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:thumbUrl completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        if (originalUrl != nil) {
            [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:originalUrl placeholderImage:image completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL){
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

This one:

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]
                                                        options:nil
                                                       progress:nil
                                                      completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                                          if (image)
                                                          {
                                                              [self.artworkImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path2] placeholderImage:image
                                                                                              completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                                                                                  if (image)
                                                                                                      NSLog(@"magic");
                                                                                              }];
                                                          }
                                                      }];
```

Comment: i'm not able to find any difference Che

Comment: Okay, if you don't like this variant, you can try another. Added to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with following code

```
UIImageView * hiddenImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

[hiddenImageView sd_setImageWithURL:thumbUrl completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

    if (image) {

        mImageView.image = image;
    }

    if (originalUrl != nil) {

        [mImageView sd_setImageWithURL:originalUrl placeholderImage:image completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL){

            if (image) {

                mImageView.image = image; // optional
            }

        }];

    }
}];
```